# State not updating when using select and options

Tags: reactjs, html-select, use-state

a bit new to this still. I have a select with dropdown options and am trying to update the 'levels' state when the option of the list changes. When I change the levels state manually it re-renders but not when using the onChange function of the select. Thanks.

```
  function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [levels, setLevels] = useState(10);
  const [list, setList] = useState(new Values('#245422').all(levels));
  

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let colors = new Values(color).all(levels);
      setList(colors);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(true);
      console.log("please enter valid color");
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <section className="container">
        <h3>color generator</h3>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={color}
            onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="#ff34sd"
            className={`${error ? "error" : null}`}
          />
          <button className="btn" type="submit">
            submit
          </button>
        </form>
        <div>
      <label htmlFor="variation" className="select-label">
        # of variations
      </label>
      <select name="variation" id="variation" onChange={(e) => {
        const selectValue = parseInt(e.target.value)
        setLevels(selectValue)
        console.log(selectValue)
      }}>
        <option value="26" default>7</option>
        <option value="10">21</option>
        <option value="6">32</option>
        <option value="4">51</option>
        <option value='2'>101</option>
      </select>

    </div>
```

Comment: What is the `new Values` in your code?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. How would I use the new operator in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your assistance I figured out that I needed to update the list rather than the levels, if that makes sense, here is what I did to make it work.

```
<select name="variation" id="variation" onChange={(e) => {
        const selectValue = parseInt(e.target.value)
        setList(new Values(`${color}`).all(selectValue))
      }}>
        <option value="26" default>7</option>
        <option value="10">21</option>
        <option value="6">32</option>
        <option value="4">51</option>
        <option value='2'>101</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have forgotten to use `value` attribute:

```
<select value={levels.toString()} name="variation" id="variation" onChange={(e) => {
        const selectValue = parseInt(e.target.value)
        setLevels(selectValue)
        console.log(selectValue)
      }}>
        <option value="26" default>7</option>
        <option value="10">21</option>
        <option value="6">32</option>
        <option value="4">51</option>
        <option value='2'>101</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Hi, tried code with added value on select and still no re-render. Thanks

Comment: I checked it, it works fine. see https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-wave-q97sn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I agree your code is fine.. the console log within the onChange handler is not indicative of if your component's state is updating.. if you look at this codepen, you will notice that the value does change as expected if you render the value: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-liskov-fxex5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes I tried to create a new component and it does update the levels value but I want the levels to also update in the list useState. Perhaps I am doing something completely wrong. I appreciate your help.